# Android service running in new process - how to determine if executing or not

Tags: android, service, process, communication

I've got a main application that starts a service. This service is sticky and is set (in AndroidManifest) to run in a different process, so that if the main application is killed it still can execute some work.
I need to know, however, if the service that is running in the distinct process is running or not, within the application that launched it.
I've thought about using a DB but it won't work if the entire app is force killed, taking the service along (since the service will not be able to update the DB to set its status to not running).

Is it possible to achieve what I'm asking here?
Thanks

Comment: Take a step back and think about this logically.  If the service is running, the service knows that.  If an Activity component is not running, then that activity doesn't know anything at all.  Code can't "know" anything unless it is running.  If you want a piece of code to know something, you have to make it run - and knowing who started it, and why, is both possible and potential informative.